# Unity3D tts & lipsync

Tags: unity-game-engine, text-to-speech, multiplatform

I am trying to develop a 2D e-learning game in Unity3D in web, Android, Windows, IOS and Mac. I need to have my avatars responding to players with text and voice articulation. I found some very lifelike voices at [www.responsivevoices.org](http://responsivevoice.org/) that I can reach via API on all platforms.

My question is: How do I connect Unity3D to Responsive Voices API?

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for the company, but the Cereproc engine does offer support for all those platforms

Comment: Is Cereproc and Responsivevoices the same company or have the same voice engine?

Answer (score 0):

This SDK created for Web development not for Unity. Try use other SDK's.

Comment: Not quite https://responsivevoice.org/api/ Responsive Voices has a full API. It is used in Chat Mapper http://www.chatmapper.com/.